# Vuejs data properties not overwritten after function call

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, vue.js, call

I'm trying to overwrite the default value of my property after an async call and print it out to the DOM. I can't understand what is wrong.

Note: I'm using single file components.

Part of my main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import CookieHandler from './lib/CookieHandler';
import Sessions from './lib/Sessions';

import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard.vue';

const cookieHandler = new CookieHandler();

// Render dashboard page
if (window.location.pathname === '/dashboard' && sessions.isSessionStarted() === true) {
  new Vue({
    el: '#dashboard',
    render: h => h(Dashboard)
  });
}
```

My component file

```
<template>
    <div id="dashboard">
        <p>{{ name }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import CookieHandler from '../lib/CookieHandler';
import request from 'request';

export default {
    name: 'Dashboard',
    data () {
        return {
            name: ''
        };
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.fetchData();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData: function () {
            const cookieHandler = new CookieHandler();

            let isLoggedIn = cookieHandler.getCookie('isLoggedIn');
            let authKey = cookieHandler.getCookie('auth');

            let options = {
                url: "<url>/service/fetch',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                form: {
                    'isLoggedIn': isLoggedIn,
                    'auth': authKey
                }
            };

            request(options, function (err, res, body) {
                if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
                    let response = JSON.parse(body);
                    this.name = response.data[0].name;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm calling the function after the component is mounted as I think this is the correct use of that property (Please correct me on that one if I'm wrong). I was trying to use computed as well.

After the function is called the name property should get overwritten by the value I get in the response.

My theory is that I'm in different scope.
If so any tips how I can keep the scope of data function? (Store the scope to a global variable?)

I was trying to use Vue.set but my problem is not what it should be used for.

Package.json file if it's going to help in anything.

```
"dependencies": {
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "watch": "^1.0.2"
  }
```

Thanks :)

### EDIT

Solved!

Comment: I think the problem is that you're using `this.name`, when `this` in that scope isn't what you think it is. Try creating a variable using `let self = this` before the request, then do `self.name = /* something */`

Comment: @JamieMcElwain Thanks that worked. It was just me messing around and trying to access the wrong object :)

Comment: Don't edit and say solved, tick the answer if it helped or if you solved it via another means, add your own answer and tick that. It helps people going forward on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Change your request methods to this:

```
request(options, (err, res, body) => {
    if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
        let response = JSON.parse(body);
        this.name = response.data[0].name;
    } else {
      this.name = err.message
    }
});
```

`() =>` will keep the scope of the current context. Currently you're `name` prop isn't the one you think you're editing.

Note: I've added an extra line to set the name to the error if you're getting one as you could be getting and error and not seeing name change because of that.